# is there a 'normal' range used for geometry_msgs::Twist values?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am implementing a drive controller which will implement a topic subscriber for the geometry_msgs::Twist message.

Is there a standard / normal range used for the X, Y, & Z values of the linear and angular members of the Twist message?

e.g. "0.0 to 1.0" or "-1.0 to 1.0" ?

I plan to support scaling but would like the default behavior to follow normal conventions and reduce the effort for users of my node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248465/is-there-a-%27normal%27-range-used-for-geometry_msgs::twist-values?/) by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 300 on 2016-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a standard / normal range used for the X, Y, & Z values of the linear and angular members of the Twist message?

tl;dr: I would say "no", as `geometry_msgs/Twist` interfaces are not supposed to work like that (they have different semantics).

---

Longer: `Twist` messages encode a linear and angular velocity relative to some reference frame. As everything in ROS that deals with 'real-world things', they are expected to follow [REP-103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html), meaning: `m/s` for linear velocities and `rad/s` for angular velocities. For [geometry_msgs/Twist](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html), that is all expressed in the receiver's local frame. For [geometry_msgs/TwistStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TwistStamped.html), the `header` field contains a target frame specification.

So a standard range wouldn't make much sense, *at this semantic level*.

Saturation at this level does make sense, and would be something basic I would include in all `Twist`-compatible drivers.

> I plan to support scaling but would like the default behavior to follow normal conventions and reduce the effort for users of my node.

Not sure this is what you mean, but nodes like [teleop_twist_joy](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy) support configurable scaling of output velocities (see the `scale_linear` and `scale_angular` parameters. These nodes are responsible for scaling input values (coming from joysticks fi) to the acceptable range of linear and angular velocities for a particular driver/platform, then output those. The contract between the `Twist` publisher and the subscriber is then such that the publisher is responsible for publishing appropriate commands.

PS: the [ros_controllers](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_controllers) packages include a [diff_drive_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller) that you may use for inspiration / something to compare your implementation against. It too implements a `geometry_msgs/Twist` interface.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2016-11-19**:
thanks.

My confusion is mostly being a noob. The various turtlesim tutorials were not explicit (or I missed the details) about what was happening and it appeared the example was using the vector3 as a generic speed value rather than as a true velocity.

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2016-11-19**:
I was further confused when I had previously read the diff_drive_controller. When it said "The controller works with a velocity twist from which it extracts the x component of the linear velocity and the z component of the angular velocity." I missed the latter reference to "units of measure".

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-19**:
Unless otherwise stated, a good assumption to make is that everything that accepts `Vector`s, `Twist`s, etc will always use SI units. In fact: if you find something that does not conform to this, you should regard it a problem, as it would violate the (implicit) contract.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-19**:\

> The controller works with a velocity twist from which it extracts the x component of the linear velocity and the z component of the angular velocity

This just means that `diff_drive_controller` will only consider linear velocities along X, and angular velocities along Z axes. It ignores the rest.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-19**:
Btw: if you have the chance, try and make your controller `ros_control` compatible. As soon as you have a `hardware_interface` implemented for your hw, you can re-use all of the rest of the infrastructure and controllers. Something like `diff_drive_controller` saves you a lot of work.

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2016-11-19**:
long long term, it may be possible to make the code `ros_control` compliant. I have only been coding ROS for 5 days and this node is for controlling basic analog RC servos using PWM. The target audience is high school students building small project robots for education and competition.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-20**:
Ok. Some reference material for the future: Dave's [ros_control_boilerplate](https://github.com/davetcoleman/ros_control_boilerplate), a Dynamixel `hardware_interface` example: [resibots/dynamixel_control_hw](https://github.com/resibots/dynamixel_control_hw).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-20**:
Btw: if you feel this question has been answered, could I ask you to mark it as such by ticking the checkbox to the left of the answer? That will clearly show the question as answered when looking at the question listing.

Thanks.

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2016-11-20**:
Thanks for the link to Dave's template. I'll improve my code with that format and structure.

(I clicked up vote but missed the check mark. Thanks)